# Vue.js - Filtering a nested array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to filter a on a nested array inside an array of objects in an Vue.js. Here's a snippet of the component code:

```
computed: {
          filteredProducts: function () { // https://codepen.io/arhey/pen/QrbxdX
            return this.products.map(product => {
                return product.filter(p => {
                    return this.powers.includes(p.total_power_lamps);
                });
            });
        }
    },
```

As a result, the data is filtered but not updated on the page.

```
filteredProducts: Array[6]
0: Array[2] <- Filtered!
1: Array[2] <- Filtered!
2: Array[0] <- Remove?
3: Array[0] <- Remove?
4: Array[0] <- Remove?
5: Array[0] <- Remove?
```

Can't update data on the page due to empty arrays.

How do I delete empty arrays ?

Comment: Have you tried skipping the empty ones in the component with a ```v-if="product!=null"``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function returns an array with same length as the original one, i recommend to use `filter` instead of `map` to return only the filled arrays :

```
computed: {
          filteredProducts: function () { 
            return this.products.filter(product => {
                return product.filter(p => {
                    return this.powers.includes(p.total_power_lamps);
                }).length>0;//return only filled arrays
            });
        }
    },
```

Comment: How do I filter multiple fields ? If one filter was selected, "OR" was triggered, if two or more filters were selected "AND".

`return this.powers.includes(p.total_power_lamps) && this.materials.includes(p.material) && this.lamps.includes(p.count_lamps)`